# validation on textbox depending on selectbox selected value change event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

validation on textbox depending on selectbox selected value change event in jquery.

Below code working fine for first time or page refresh case.

but if i select 'NID' first  and again change to 'PST' length part working when i select 'PST' first  and again change to 'NID' length part notworking.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#seIdproof').change(function(){ 
        var PFID = $('#seIdproof').val();   
        $('#seCustomerId').val('');

        if(PFID == 'PST'){
                $('#seCustomerId').keyup(function(e) {

                    var len3=$(this).val().length;
                    if (len3 > 6){
                        alert("This Id proof number is not valid,Please enter valid number.");
                         $(this).val('');
                    }


                }); 

        }
        if(PFID == 'NID'){
            $('#seCustomerId').keyup(function(e) {

                    var len1=$(this).val().length;
                    if (len1 > 11){
                        alert("This Id proof number is not valid,Please enter valid number.");
                         $(this).val('');
                    }
                });

        }
});
});
```

Can anybody please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try use .keyup(function(e) { 
and add this code
e.preventDefault()

delete lines of return code and only put $(this).val('');

Comment: can you please in my code where i need to put e.preventDefault()

Comment: thanks for reply, i have updated my question as per your suggestion still getting issue.

Comment: if(PFID == 'PST'){
$('#seCustomerId').keyup(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
 var len3=$(this).val().length;
if (len3 > 6){
 alert("This Id proof....");
 $(this).val('');
                    }


                }); 

        }
        if(PFID == 'NID'){
            $('#seCustomerId').keyup(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
                    var len1=$(this).val().length;
                    if (len1 > 11){
                        alert("This Id proof number is not valid,Please enter valid number.");
                         $(this).val('');
    }
                });
        } 
Gooluck